# Detecting USB in c++

Tags: c++, windows, daemon

iam trying to develop a tool which runs as daemon process in windows and it always tracks the usb insertion.i.e if a new usb is inserted it verifies the usb and allows the user to access,and if it is not an valid usb ,it simply don't allow the user to access it.
I have gone through all the search results i made on google but i was not able to follow,can you guys please tell ,from where should i start and even i went through [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

I want to develop the tool in C++.Please help me with your suggestion and links for developing.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Out of curiousity, how do you plan on blocking access? Also "was not able to follow" is not enough information. You need to show us [what have you treid](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Hey Scott,i thought blocking can be done by not allowing system to install device drivers.

Answer (score 0):

This information on www.codeproject.com may help your question , but it is in C# language . If you understand the steps in this example , you'll find it easy.

[Detecting usb devices in windows using c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60579/A-USB-Library-to-Detect-USB-Devices)

If you know about mono framework you'll be able to port this project to run on linux environment.